# Proving Zero-One law for tail events using Bluementhal's law.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, brownian-motion

I am reading the book Brownian Motion by Yuval Peres and Peter Morters which can be found [here][1].

Tail algebra for a  brownian motion $\{B(t): t\geq 0\}$ is defined as $\mathcal{T} = \bigcap_{t\geq 0} \mathcal{G}(t)$ where $\mathcal{G}(t) = \sigma(B(s): s \geq t)$. The zero-one law for tail events says that:

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and suppose $A \in \mathcal{T}$ is a tail event. Then $P_x(A) \in \{0,1\}$.

The book says that the proof follows from time inversion and Bluementhals 0-1 law (Which has the same conclusion except $A \in \mathcal{F}^+(0) \left( = \bigcap_{t> 0} \mathcal{F}^0(s) \text{ where } \mathcal{F}^0(s) = \sigma(B(t): 0 \leq t \leq s\right)$). I don't understand how it follows from time inversion. Here is what I think they mean but I am not sure:

$$X(t) = tB(\frac{1}{t}) \text{ if $t \neq 0$ and } 0 \text{ otherwise } $$
be the time inverted brownian motion. From this I think the following is true (But not sure):

$$\sigma(B(s): s \geq t) = \sigma(X(s): 0 \leq s \leq 1/t)$$
And thus $A \in \mathcal{T} \implies A \in \bigcap_{t > 0} \sigma(X(s): 0 \leq  s \leq t) $
Now the bluementhals law applies to show that $P_x(A) \in \{0,1\}$ (as X and B have the same law).

Is my approach correct or do I need to do something more? Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant that only. Typo while Texing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows immediately from Bluementhal's $0-1$ law applied to the BM $(X(s))$ since $\sigma(X(s): 0 \leq s \leq 1/t)=\sigma(B(s): s \geq t)$ which implies $\bigcap_{t\geq 0} \mathcal{G}(t)=\bigcap_{t > 0} \sigma(X(s): 0 \leq  s \leq t) $.

Comment: just to make sure I got you correctly: does that just mean that $A \in \cap_{t \geq 0} \sigma(B(s): s \geq t )$ implies $A \in \mathcal{F}^+(0) = \bigcap_{t > 0} \sigma(X(s): 0 \leq s \leq t)$. From this the bluementhal's law gives $P_x(A) = 0$. And the result is correct because both the brownian motions have the same law?

Comment: Exactly. I just edited the answer when you were typing the comment. @Mathaddict

Comment: Thank you I got it now .

Comment: you might be interested in the following question as well :) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467356/difficulty-in-understanding-proof-of-a-result-regarding-local-extrema-of-brownia