# Difficulty in understanding proof of a result regarding local extrema of Brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, brownian-motion

The following is a theorem in the book Brownian motion by Yuval Peres and Peter Morters. I have one difficulty in understanding the proof:

> Theorem 2.11 For a linear Brownian motion $\{B(t): 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1\}$, almost surely,
> (a) every local maximum is a strict local maximum;
> (b) the set of times where the local maxima are attained is countable and dense;
> (c) the global maximum is attained at a unique time.
> Proof. We first show that, given two nonoverlapping closed time intervals, i.e. such that their interiors are disjoint, the maxima of Brownian motion on them are different almost surely. Let $\left[a_{1}, b_{1}\right]$ and $\left[a_{2}, b_{2}\right]$ be two fixed intervals with $b_{1} \leqslant a_{2}$. Denote by $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$, the maxima of Brownian motion on these two intervals. Note first that, by the Markov property together with Theorem $2.8$, almost surely $B\left(a_{2}\right)<$ $m_{2}$. Hence this maximum agrees with maximum in the interval $\left[a_{2}-\frac{1}{n}, b_{2}\right]$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and we may therefore assume in the proof that $b_{1}<a_{2}$.
> Applying the Markov property at time $b_{1}$ we see that the random variable $B\left(a_{2}\right)-B\left(b_{1}\right)$ is independent of $m_{1}-B\left(b_{1}\right)$. Using the Markov property at time $a_{2}$ we see that $m_{2}-B\left(a_{2}\right)$ is also independent of both these variables. The event $m_{1}=m_{2}$ can be written as
> $$
> B\left(a_{2}\right)-B\left(b_{1}\right)=m_{1}-B\left(b_{1}\right)-\left(m_{2}-B\left(a_{2}\right)\right) .
> $$
> Conditioning on the values of the random variables $m_{1}-B\left(b_{1}\right)$ and $m_{2}-B\left(a_{2}\right)$, the left hand side is a continuous random variable and the right hand side a constant, hence this event has probability 0 .

What exactly have we done here in the last step? How do we get that the probability of the event $$
B\left(a_{2}\right)-B\left(b_{1}\right)=B\left(a_{2}\right)-B\left(b_{1}\right)-\left(m_{2}-B\left(a_{2}\right)\right) .
$$
Is zero, from the given argument? The only information that we have is that the random variables $B\left(a_{2}\right)-B\left(b_{1}\right)$, $B\left(a_{2}\right)-B\left(b_{1}\right)$ and $\left(m_{2}-B\left(a_{2}\right)\right)$ are independent.

Can someone elaborate the argument a bit. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are independent r.v.'s. Let $U=Y-Z$. Then $P(X=U)=\int P(X=u)dF_U(u)$ (by conditioning on $U$) where $F_U$ is the distribution function of $U$. If $X$ has  continuous distribution then $P(X=u)=0$ for all $u$ so $\int P(X=u)dF_U(u)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it.

Comment: Isn't this saying that two independent (continuous) random variables always agree with probability zero (ie almost surely disagree)? Is that true/sensible?

Comment: @TanishqKumar That is very true and it follows from Fubini's Theorem or by a simple conditioning argument.